# Webpage not found error when uploading large file in php

Tags: php

I have read all the existing related topics. But, no one has seems to encounter similar problem. Hence, creating a new query.

I have set the variable appropriately in php.ini file to allow upload of files upto 128 MB.
Restarted the apache server as well after changing the php.ini.
I am able to upload small files without any issues. However, the moment I upload a file larger than 20MB I get error

1) on Chrome browser - upload.php page not found. However, when I refresh chrome is able to find that page.
2) on Firefox and IE - Internal Server error.

Nothing can be found in server error logs. I tried setting error reporting on on the php page.
Probably, the page is not getting loaded at all and hence, no error is getting reported.

I have been stuck with this since last two days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `<?php set_time_limit(0);` on top of your PHP Script

Comment: Thanks Shankar, I just tried that. However, had no luck. :(

Comment: The issue was "MaxRequestLen" variable in "conf/last_httpd.include" config file.
I increased its value by multiplying it by 10 to resolve the issue.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was "MaxRequestLen" variable in "conf/last_httpd.include" config file.
I increased its value by multiplying it by 10 to resolve the issue.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Comment: Hi
I'm also having same issue can you please let me know path of above mentioned file and how can I change its value.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your php to upload big files

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
ini_set('max_input_time', '600');
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); // no memory limit
php_value upload_max_filesize 750M
php_value post_max_size 750M
```

Comment: Thanks jetawe, Here are my setting from php.ini                               upload_max_filesize 128M 128M                                               post_max_size 128M 128M                                                   max_execution_time 6000 6000                                                 max_input_time 6000 6000                                                memory_limit -1 -1                                                   however, this is not helping. Where do I need to set the last two values ?